Is it possible to calculate FPS (frames per second) of video using statistical data?
There are parameters:

Video bitrate.
Frame height.
Frame width.
Video duration.

With this data, is it possible to determine the number of frames per second without actually playing the video?
A similar question I asked:

How to find out the fps of a video stream/ffmpeg?

The difference is that in it I initially try to enter the number of frames for each stream in manifest.mpd using FFmpeg. In the future, just get the manifest data via JavaScript. Which would be great, but since there is no help. Probably it is impossible
It is probably possible to take the video data in JavaScript, count and get the frames. I think so, I hope that at least this way it is possible to get the FPS for the video stream.

Corrected, there is a difference from the question. In the first case, enter the FPS via FFMPEG. In this case, calculate the number of frames based on the data that I have in JavaScript

The FPS (if not variable) is usually in a metadata field at the start of the stream somewhere.

If you’re generating the manifest yourself, can you not just add the pre-computed FPS info to that? And even if not, then as @OrangeDog points out most container or codec formats for video do have provisions for storing the FPS in metadata (though you may need to add that yourself as part of processing, since it’s not always mandatory that the field is populated).

I downloaded a video from YouTube, there is no information about FPS in the metadata. YouTube somehow determines FPS for each stream...

As @OrangeDog alludes to, some videos may not even have a consistent FPS - for example, if the video is being captured from a source over a network and a frame had to be dropped in transit. YouTube knows what framerates it has because they convert uploaded videos to be that way. If you're trying to work with arbitrary video files, you don't have that luxury.

No, not with just those 4 statistics. Also, if compression is in use, it's hard to calculate anything because you wouldn't know how compressible the video data is.
For uncompressed video, to find the FPS, you would need to know:

Pixels per frame (so the frame height and width in pixels).
Bits per pixel (so the bit depth per color channel and the chroma subsampling mode like "4:2:2").
Bitrate (could be derived from file size and precise duration).

